# Grey shadow that is visible even after a clean shave called?

Tags: single-word-requests

Like on this guys face on the right
[image]

Comment: It's just very short stubble.

Comment: I assume you don't want *designer stubble* or *five o'clock shadow*? Haven't heard anything specifically for the tint remaining right after a shave.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most common name seems to be a 5 o'clock shadow.
Stubble is used as well to describe a short beard, although usually in the form of "heavy stubble" where it describes a 10-day beard of a few mms.
Permashadow, or perma-shadow, is a slang word that is used in online forums to describe the outline of the beard that is still visible on a clean shaved face.